# Why does this code fail to run in PHP but works fine in Management Studio

Tags: php, sql-server, ssms, database-backups, database-restore

I am trying to back up and restore the database from an older backup.

I use this SQL code to do this:

```
ALTER DATABASE [UKBYTEDB] SET RECOVERY FULL;

BACKUP DATABASE [UKBYTEDB] TO DISK = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/UKBYTEDB/dev/UKBYTEDB- 2017-02-20.Bak' WITH FORMAT, MEDIANAME = 'Z_SQLServerBackups', NAME = 'Full Backup of [UKBYTEDB] - 2017-02-20';

ALTER DATABASE UKBYTEDB SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE; 

BACKUP LOG UKBYTEDB TO DISK = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/UKBYTEDB/dev/UKBYTEDB-LOG- 2017-02-20.Bak' WITH NORECOVERY
RESTORE DATABASE [UKBYTEDB] FROM DISK = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/UKBYTEDB/dev/UKBYTEDB-defualt.Bak' WITH RECOVERY;
```

My PHP Code with connection to Master DB:

```
$RUN = sqlsrv_query($masterDBlink,$RestoreDefualtDB);   
if($RUN === false) 
{ 
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors())); 
} 
else 
{ 
    echo 'Done!'; 
}
```

Then I get this error:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 01000 [SQLSTATE] => 01000 [1] => 4035 [code] => 4035 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Processed 2304 pages for database 'UKBYTEDB', file 'wardobsliveisle' on file 1. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Processed 2304 pages for database 'UKBYTEDB', file 'wardobsliveisle' on file 1. ) ) 1
```

Comment: That's not an error message.

Comment: @JayBlanchard do you have any idea why it fails and returns false?

Answer (score 0):

If the code is working in Management Studio and your connection is good, I suggest you put NOCOUNT before your first statement and see if it works:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
ALTER DATABASE [UKBYTEDB]...
```

Comment: I tested it with NOCOUNT but still shows same output. The I tried USE MASTER before the statement and the return was TRUE instead of false no errors but the backup file didn't save. I have tested the connection its fine i can insert, delete and select it's just the backup fails.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found something that got it to work:

add this code right after the connection

```
sqlsrv_configure( "WarningsReturnAsErrors", 0 );
```

then add this after the backup and restore query

```
 usleep(600);
 set_time_limit(2000);
```

then run this query at the end of the code

```
$sql = "USE [UKBYTEDB]";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($masterDBlink, $sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem--the query wasn't working in PHP but the query worked in SQL Management Studio. It turned out that the stored procedure I was executing had a couple of PRINT statements in it, left over from debugging. Once I removed those statements, it worked.